# Unity has stopped working / DirectX10 Card / D3D10Level9.dll caused an Access Violation

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]Unity won't start my existing Project, nor a new one.

Since my HD4870 was slowly dying, my Pc froze a few times while workig with Unity.

The Card died, r.i.p

Now I'm On an old HD4890@1gb, directX 10 card

(unity minimum requirements says directX 10 card are ok https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/system-requirements.html)

**What i tried so far:**

-Uninstall Unity Hub & all existing Unity versions - > Reinstall
-starting unity with "-force-glcore"  "-force-glcore" "-force-d3d11" "-force-d3d10"

ERROR LOG: https://textuploader.com/1l7hp!

Comment: added my error log

Answer (score 1):

Unity won't start under Windows 10 when you have an AMD Radeon HD4890 / 4800 Series.

because:

*These graphics products must be installed using display driver version: **8.970.100.9001.** This driver is provided as a courtesy and only available via Windows Update. Please enable Windows Update and allow it to detect and install the appropriate driver.*

FIX:

Go to your Device Manager -> Graphics -> Right click on "ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series" -> properties -> Update drivers